# Who's behind the UI design of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, design

What's their major and job title?

I think they're awesome and created a good look and feel with the use of only a few images.

Comment: I agree entirely, but bear in mind that SO is aimed at a very specialised group of users. It wouldn't suit the general public. I mean, where are the emoticons?

Comment: @Shore: This is a fantastic question... wish I could do a +10 here :)

Answer (score 12):

[Jeremy Kratz](http://www.jeremykratz.com/index.php/work/stack-overflow/) is the primary designer of Stack Overflow. Don't know what he majored in (you'd have to ask him) but he is a professional designer.

Comment: Wow! The work at his website is absolutely amazing... any idea what technologies/tools does he use?

Comment: Do you know what's SO like before the design?

Comment: That URL doesn't work anymore. Here's the URL for Jeremy Kratz's website now http://www.jeremykratz.com/Default.aspx StackOverflow is there, August 2008! Thank you, I was curious who designed the SO site originally!

Answer (score 3):

Call me a bonehead but I found the UI a bit confusing at first:

1. I'd search by entering my criteria
   in the Search box, but I kept on
   clicking the Ask Question button to
   execute my search.
2. I found that placement of the tabs
   (Newest, Featured, etc) over the
   question count and ads to be
   confusing.

I've since gotten used to the UI though, and find it simple, easy to use and very utilitarian.

Comment: I would also frequently start typing my search queries into the interesting tags text area.

Comment: One beef I still have is the search bar. It's practically useless unless you put a + before every word. Even the friendly giant Google uses AND searching by default. Jeesh. But no, other than that, an awsome ui experience.